# Search subversion via TortoiseSVN for values inside files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm looking for a way to search subversion to find any file where a certain server name is referenced.  Is there fairly straight forward way to create a list or report based on a value in the files?

Answer (score 2):

`svn cat` will print the contents of a file in a Subversion repository; you can pipe the output of this command through `grep` or `find` or some other tool that searches files for strings.